# How can I make a function that performs a depth-first search that stops when it finds a given vertex?

Tags: python

Hi I am new to python and I am struggling with what we are doing in an activity. I don't quite get how to finish this code so that it can perform a depth-first search that stops when it finds a given vertex.

```
graph = {'0': ['1', '2'],
         '1': ['0', '3', '4'],
         '2': ['0', '4'],
         '3': ['1', '4'],
         '4': ['1', '2', '3', '5'],
         '5': ['4', '6'],
         '6': ['5']}



def dfs(visited, graph, vertex):
        print (vertex)
        visited.append(vertex)
        for neighbour in graph[vertex]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                dfs(visited, graph, neighbour)
            
# implement this function
def dfs_stop(visited, graph, vertex, target):
    pass

dfs([], graph, '0')

print

dfs_stop([], graph, '0', '4')
```

Comment: how about just perform a simple checking that `vertex == target` ?

Comment: Why are you using 2 functions for 1 DFS?

Comment: I need to implement the code under but i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a check if the source node is equal to the target node before calling the DFS on its neighbors.

```py
def dfs_stop(visited, graph, vertex, target):
        print (vertex)
        visited.append(vertex)
        if (vertex == target):        # to break/stop the function
            return
        for neighbour in graph[vertex]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                dfs_stop(visited, graph, neighbour)
```